# Question on $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} P(|Y_n| \geq c) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac 1n$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Consider a sequence of discrete random variables $Y_n$ with the following distribution:

$$P(Y_n = y) = \begin{cases} 1 - \frac 1n, & \text{for } y = 0, \\ \frac 1n, & \text{for } y = n^2, \\ 0, & \text{elsewhere}. \end{cases}$$

For every $c$ $>$ $0$, we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} P(|Y_n| \geq c) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac 1n = 0.$$

I do not understand the step: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} P(|Y_n| \geq c) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac 1n$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $Y_n$ is either 0 or strictly positive and since $c$ is strictly
postivie, take $N$ to be a sufficiently large integer (such as for example $N^2>c$), then for every $n >N$
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \Pr \left[ Y_n \geqslant c \right] & = & \Pr \left[ Y_n \neq 0 \right]\\
  & = & \frac{1}{n}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Sorry but $\Pr \left[ Y_n \geqslant c \right] = \Pr \left[ Y_n \neq 0 \right]$ is not always true.